# How can I use "#FFFF00" in vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

When I attempt to use `label1.ForeColor="#FFFF00"` I get an error: "Specified cast is not valid."

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do like...

```
Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("#FFFF00")
```

Comment: for this line of code, there is difference between c# and vb.net code except " ; " .... :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`WebColorConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcolorconverter.aspx) class.

It has a [`ConvertFromString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25ds5cb6.aspx) method that can be used like this:

```
Dim ColorString As String = "#FFFF00"
Dim Color_Converter As New ColorConverter
Dim ActualColor As Color = Color_Converter.ConvertFromString(ColorString)
```